# Handling MySQL Full Text Special Characters

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

When using MySQL full text search in boolean mode there are certain characters like + and - that are used as operators. If I do a search for something like "C++" it interprets the + as an operator. What is the best practice for dealing with these special characters?

The current method I am using is to convert all + characters in the data to _plus. It also converts &,@,/ and # characters to a textual representation.

Answer (score 5):

There's no way to do this in nicely using MySQL's full text search. What you're doing (substituting special characters with a pre-defined string) is the only way to do it.

You may wish to consider using [Sphinx Search](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/) instead. It apparently supports escaping special characters, and by all reports is significantly faster than the default full text search.

Answer (score 4):

MySQL is fairly brutal in what tokens it ignores when building its full text indexes.  I'd say that where it encountered the term "C++" it would probably strip out the plus characters, leaving only C, and then ignore that because it's too short.  You could probably configure MySQL to include single-letter words, but it's not optimised for that, and I doubt you could get it to treat the plus characters how you want.

If you have a need for a good internal search engine where you can configure things like this, check out [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) which has been ported to various languages [including PHP (in the Zend framework)](http://ifacethoughts.net/2008/02/07/zend-brings-lucene-to-php/).

Or if you need this more for 'tagging' than text search then something else may be more appropriate.