# mysql full text search question

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a full-text indexed column named resolution. The data in it looks like :

```
some row: 480*800 480*848 480*854 600*1024 600*800 720*1280
```

my SQL doing the full-text search is:

```
... MATCH(resolution) AGAINST('480' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

And the above row is returned. It looks to me that the '*' symbol is considered as some kind of delimiter which in my case it shouldn't be the case. What I wanted is that the row only shows up in SQLs like this:

```
... MATCH(resolution) AGAINST('480*800' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

what can I do to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried escaping it with a backslash ` \ ` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't do it in mysql full text search, as it is not designed for this.

Quick search leads to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290581/handling-mysql-full-text-special-characters) which is a possible workaround, but would require to alter the data...

If you'll consider altering source data - it would probably be best to put it in a separate table with 2 fields (W & H) and one-to-many relationship to your main table; then do a regular "WHERE W = 400" query to achieve what you need.